# Craft CMS not working on server

Tags: server

I had my Craft CMS site working on my local hosting. I then moved it over to bluehost VPS. I moved the database and uploaded the files to the server. I've put the database user information in the .env file and the server location. But site comes back on domain:

> Service Unavailable
>   Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

When I try to admin in it tells me:

> Service Unavailable
>   Craft isn’t installed yet.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Check if you have done `composer install` in your craft folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you clone a project to the server you have to reinstall craft just like you did locally, you have the files but nothing is installed.

- **Enter to your server;** for expample with `ssh root@your_ip`
- **Navigate to your path project;** for example, on an Ubuntu - NGINX server it would be something like this: `cd /var/www/html`
- **Intall Craft:** `php craft install` *(make sure you have the correct database credentials in .env file)*
- **If you use Composer and NPM install the dependencies:** `composer install && npm install`

Then you should have Craft installed.
More info about installation [here.](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/installation.html#step-1-download-craft)

Answer (score 0):

> Service Unavailable Craft isn’t installed yet.

If you're getting that message, then Craft can connect to the database with the credentials you've provided, but it can't find the `info` table, so it thinks it's not installed.

Maybe the `tablePrefix` config setting is set incorrectly in your `.env` file?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My DB_TABLE_PREFIX setting is set to craft_ (which is correct). Is there anything else that could be causing it?

Comment: In my case, it turned out to be a corrupted config file.